# combine ls with grep and regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep, ls

In the /usr/bin folder on ubuntu 14.10, I try to search for files that start with the letter x.
My command is : ls | grep ^x

It doesn't work (no result) but I don't know why since ls x* return 162 results.

After inspection, I think it comes from the ls command. When I use ls | grep ^........x (8 points) I obtain all the files starting by a "x". I have the same problem with $: when I use ls | grep .....e$ (5 points) I obtain all the files ending by a "e".

When I try the guest session, the command works. I have may be a conflict with a conf file ? How can I resolve that?

Comment: It works for me. What do you mean with "It doesn't work"? Why don't you use `ls /usr/bin/x*`?

Comment: It doesn't work means I have 0 results. The ls x* works (162 results) but I want to use grep (training). The command ls | grep x (512 results) works but when I add ^ I have nothing. I don't know why.

Comment: Hmmm, which shell do you use?

Comment: I work on ubuntu 14.10. The shell is bash.

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce it in bash (albeit in Mint), it works for me. Is grep an alias with some "bogus" parameters: `alias|grep grep`? What happens when you use `ls | grep -e ^x`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the alias ls='ls --color'.
To solve my problem I just have to unalias or to use \ls | grep ^x.

The alias ls='ls --color=auto' also works.